# Using multiple hubs with Signal-R

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket, signalr

I'm a bit new to using signalr. I'm dealing with a system that will work with more than one client from a server. I wanted to create a separate hub for each client, but when I add a new hub, the other one becomes inoperable.

Here is the error I get when I try to connect with the client:

```
`[2022-11-03T15:01:03.952Z] Information: WebSocket connected to wss://localhost:7178/chatHub?id=fwNf0IydU6eYjOMPq9JQsw.
signalr.js:455 [2022-11-03T15:01:04.038Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error. InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hubs.AbpHubBase' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and all parameters of a public constructor are either registered as services or passed as arguments. Also ensure no extraneous arguments are provided.'.
log @ signalr.js:455
_stopConnection @ signalr.js:2709
transport.onclose @ signalr.js:2647
_close @ signalr.js:2302
stop @ signalr.js:2279
_stopInternal @ signalr.js:2445
await in _stopInternal (async)
stop @ signalr.js:2426
_stopInternal @ signalr.js:1151
_processIncomingData @ signalr.js:1386
HubConnection.connection.onreceive @ signalr.js:985
webSocket.onmessage @ signalr.js:2236`
```

ChatHub.cs like this:

`public class ChatHub : AbpHubBase, ISingletonDependency`

and these are my endpoints:

```
                endpoints.MapHub<AbpHubBase>("/chatHub");
                endpoints.MapHub<ChatHubV>("/chatHubV2");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved the problem. I didn't need to inherit from AbpHubBase. When I returned to the Hub class, I was able to use it with two separate endpoints.